# framework not found AudioUnit

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob

I have a problem implementing AdMob into my project. I added all frameworks, removed some. I tried to run the project after deleting every code connected to AdMob and still getting same error, so I am sure that the error is not caused by coding.

```
ld: framework not found AudioUnit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Framework not found AudioUnit
```

I tried to remove AudioUnit and add some other audio frameworks like CoreAudio etc. (according to some answers) and still nothing. All errors I get after putting AdMob file into my project.

Comment: did you link the library search paths?

Comment: If you mean to link -ObjC in Other Linker Flags, then yes I did.

Comment: in 'Build settings' search for 'search paths' and set them to the right locations. not sure if that is the problem but it can be. (did you try setting the -v in clang as suggested by the error)

Comment: I tried, but still got error